# Google kubernetes monitoring, stuck loading resources

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, monitoring, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a kubernetes cluster created on GCP, it's fully functional, every logs/metrics are enabled on GKE but, when I go to Stackdriver/resources/kubernetes engine nothing is showed, stuck in loading page.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a specific problem with GCP. I assume you don't have enterprise support in that case I recommend opening a ticket with the [free trial support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/free_trial_support). Otherwise, you'll have to sign up for Silver level support which is $150/month

Comment: you can also open a [Public issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/) for free since this is likely an issue on with GCP